# Change image in a certain place using span with HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css, hover

When the cursor is on the 2nd span, the photo will change and when the cursor is moved, the old photo will come.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid SO isn't an ab initio coding service. We are very happy to help but we help  you debug code so please put what you have tried into your question with a description of what isn't working. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will require a little bit of JavaScript, but it can be put in your HTML document. The span tag can have a hover event call the JavaScript to change the image. Here is a simple example.

```
<img id="sampleImg">
<span id="span1" onmouseover="document.getElementById('sampleImg').src = 'image1.gif'"> Span 1</span>
<span id="span2" onmouseover="document.getElementById('sampleImg').src = 'image2.gif'">Span 2</span>
```

The image source paths will need changed to fit your needs, but otherwise this should be able to be implemented into your code. The onmouseover event in the span tag contains the JavaScript to change the given image's source.

I hope this solved your issue!